# User provisioning in Salesforce from servicedesk application

Tags: user-management

I have a following requirement:

Client uses a servicedesk application to request, approve, notify, and track access granted to various on-premises and cloud applications, including Salesforce. Salesforce is currently used to authenticate users. Users should be provisioned in Salesforce as soon as they are approved in the servicedesk application (with the approved profiles and permission sets).

What would be the right way to achieve it ?

Following options came to my mind:

a) Can Salesforce login flow handle this ? Not sure since I think login flow cannot create users.
b) Am not sure if JIT provisioning can be used since it would dependent on serviceDesk's capability to handle SAML.
c) I think the solution can be as simple as servicedesk application calling an API to salesforce to create users. Any ideas ?

Any pointers ?

Comment: You have either an option to integrate via APIs (by giving the service desk application access rights on behalf of an admin which could be a security risk); or via SAML JIT provisioning.

Comment: You can use SSO in salesforce, and it does provide auto provisioning of user.

Comment: agree, SSO should be the first way to go, let us know how did you go with that